# Delphi : How can solve click issue for a Form which it's parent is a ScrollBox?

Tags: delphi

I Created a Project with 2 form. TForm1 (main form) and TForm2. on Form1 we have a ScrollBox. on Form2 we have 2 TEdit. and in OnCreate of Form1 we have the following code.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm:TForm2;
begin
  frm:=TForm2.Create(ScrollBox1);
  frm.Parent:=ScrollBox1;
  frm.Show;
end;
```

when I run the program I see an instance of TForm2 in the Scrollbox1. everything looks good. when mouse hover close or minimize or maximize buttons or any other button on the form everything seems normal. but when click on one Edit or any other component that has typing ability on it the focus can not go to that TEdit or component. Only if I Right-Click on that component the focus goes to it.

Is it possible to fix this problem? and if yes how can I do it?

and MDIForm can not help me. because I need more than one form with ability of hosting some other forms in them. and delphi seems to not support mdiForm for non-mainForms. if this issue about click can be solved I think it is a good choice for me to manage some forms to host some other forms.

Comment: Don't embed a Form like this. Use a Frame instead of a Form. As for MDI, it is *technically* possible to have multiple `fsMDIForm` parent Forms active at one time, but it is a lot of work to bypass the VCL's restrictions (the restrictions are not in Win32 itself): [Multiple MDI Parent Forms in a single Application](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23574)

Comment: @Remy Embedding forms is normal. The Delphi IDE is based on this concept, dock sites and so on. Frames are fine. But what if you want them to stand alone. Then you need a form to act as a host for the frame. Is that better than making forms be children? Not in my experience.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see embedding (simply setting `Parent`) and docking (dock sites) as separate features. The VCL has specific code for supporting docking. But whenever someone uses Forms as simple children, there is usually something that goes wrong with it, which always makes me think Forms are not well-designed for embedding, whereas Frames are specifically designed for it since they are always children and never free-floating.

Comment: why exactly can you not use mdiforms ? You can embed forms on mdichild forms just as you can on your mainform.

Comment: Set border style of the second form to bsNone.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  setting the border style to bsNone does seem to fix the issue, but then OP loses min/max/close buttons etc.. not sure if that's the intention..

Comment: @John - Sure. I'd still post an answer if I knew why the border does matter. With the border, I'd use the API SetParent, instead of VCL's parenting.

Comment: @GuidoG I mentioned why I can't use mdi-from. because only one form in your application which is the MainForm can be Mdi form. but delphi currently doesn't support Multi mid form. I need multi mdi forms.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz hmm. Interesting! why the border cause the problem? can it be solved? but if not. your comment is useful I think. I can create new form and make my own (min-max-close) buttons and border and other stuff on it like titlebar and new forms that need to be child can be inherited from this new form.Thanks. +1 for your nice comment! :)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Unfortunately this approach is not usable for me. I think I should change the whole program. because I have FMX form which is parented by the child forms that I mentioned. and those fmx forms not visible in the panel that I put on the child forms when I make child parent to Scrollbox. but it is not the question that I asked here. thanks anyway.