# How to 'parent' a form? (Controls won't accept focus)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a child form 'frmTest' and a main form 'TfrmMain'. I set the main form as parent for frmTest like this:

```
unit Main;

INTERFACE
USES
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Forms, Test, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Controls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

IMPLEMENTATION  {$R *.dfm}
 
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR frmTest: TChildForm;
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TChildForm, frmTest);
  //frmTest:= TForm1.Create(Self);
  frmTest.Parent:= Self;
  frmTest.Show;
  frmTest.SetFocus;
end;
```

---

```
unit test;  { THIS IS THE CHILD }

INTERFACE

TYPE
  TChildForm = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    SpinEdit1: TSpinEdit;
  end;
```

[Code as ZIP](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27175170815860262046)

But controls (edit box, spin edit, etc) in frmInsertImg will not accept focus from mouse but can be focused with Tab.

What am I doing wrong?

---

PS: Of course I should have used CanFocus before SetFocus. But even so,  CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). It needs to be [fixed](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)

Comment: We don't want a ZIP, just a [mcve] in the Q

Comment: Full example posted in the Q

Comment: Add `frmTest.BorderStyle := bsNone` and it's all good. I doubt you really want the form's non-client chrome showing like this was a top level window. Normally you'd set `Align` to `alClient` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks BorderStyle solved the problem BUT the child window now looks like a panel AND I want to show borders badly. I want the child window look like a real window. This child form is a short lived 'property editor'. The user works mostly in the parent window and from time to time it will invoke the property editor to change some properties then quickly close the editor.

Comment: You want to allow the form to be dragged around inside the parent form? Really?

Comment: Ok. Soory about the caption. I don't care about drag. BUT I want to have the borders in order t have a clear delimitation between the parent and the child. Now, without border the child blends into the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134961/discussion-between-darkpresidentofamerica-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: Including `WS_CAPTION` seems to be what screws up the mouse interaction. I would strongly recommend that you abandon your current plan and use `bsNone`. If you need to provide a frame for visual reasons, do that.

Comment: thanks. please post your solution as answer and I accept it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674426/delphi-how-can-solve-click-issue-for-a-form-which-its-parent-is-a-scrollbox

Comment: Thanks Sertac for link.

Comment: @DarkPresidentOfAmerica "*This child form is a short lived 'property editor'. The user works mostly in the parent window and from time to time it will invoke the property editor to change some properties then quickly close the editor.*" So what's wrong with using a modal popup Form instead? Why does it have to be embedded in the Parent Form? Otherwise, consider using MDI instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` for the child form. I'm not sure of the exact reasons why this works, but it has the desired effect.

If you need to add a visual frame for your child form then that is best done with explicit UI for the contained of your child form.

Forms aren't really intended to be used in this way, in my opinion. You can make things mostly work, but it's not terribly robust. Putting the UI into a frame and then hosting that should lead to better behaviour.

Comment: "I'm not sure of the exact reasons why this works" - I JUST WANTED toask you why the hell this woks :) It seems unrelated :) How could border affect focus?

Comment: Focus is just one of those things that goes a bit screwy when you parent a form. Forms aren't really designed for that. A cleaner design would be to use a frame.