# Setting Form Parent causes controls to be inactive

Tags: delphi

I can move a form to the position I want and make it visible.
The controls on the form, Edits, spin edits etc all work as expected.

```
If Button = mbRight then // RIGHT Button inside Field Panel gets Form

begin
  Form.Left := (Sender as TAdvShape).Left;
  Form.Top := (Sender as TAdvShape).Top + (Sender as TAdvShape).Height + 10;
  Form.Visible := True;
  // Form.parent := frmBodyPlan.pnlField;
end
```

When I uncomment the `Form.parent := frmBodyPlan.pnlField;` The form appears in the right position in its new parent but the controls do not act correctly.

If the control is a spin edit the up/down spinner advance the value of the control but the user cannot stripe the field of control and edit it.

The pnlField is a TRzPanel.

What do I need to do to regain functionality after assigning parent?

(using Rio and Windows 10 32 bit)

Comment: If the border of the `Form` (that you want to show) is something else than `bsNone` it will not work with parenting the form. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42065369/2292722 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38674426/2292722 . Either set form border to `bsNone` or use frames (`TFrame`) instead of forms.

Comment: I had never used Frames before but switching to them solved a multitude of problems. Thanks @Tom